# Fetch whole table row data into javascript variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I have a html table like this:

```
| name | type   | edit |
| zzz  | aaaa   | edit |
| xxx  | bbbb   | edit |
| mmm  | cccc   | edit |
```

So, what I am trying to do is that, If I press edit against the 2nd row I want the data "xxx"
and "bbb" to be stored in some javascript variables for further use

I found this snippet of code. but it will only give me the cell which is clicked but not the whole row

```
$('#tableID').click(function(e){
    alert($(e.target).text()); // using jQuery
})
```

**UPDATE:**
so heres my table cell structure

```
<tr>
        <td> <?php echo $row['name'] ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
        <td class="edit_button">Edit</td> 
</tr>
```

and this is the JS I have used against it

```
$("#table_id").on("click", ".edit_button", function() {
                    var data = $(this).closest("td").siblings().map(function() {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).toArray();
            }); 
            alert(data[0]);
            alert(data[1]);
            alert(data[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$tr=$(e.target).closest("tr");
```

This will store the table row in a variable.

you could then access each of the td cells with this:

```
$tr.find('td').each(function(){alert($(this).text())});
```

here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/snowburnt/N85uA/

Answer (score 1):

I would use event delegation instead of `e.target`. Just give your edit buttons a class.

```
$("tableID").on("click", ".edit_button", function() {
    var data = $(this).closest("td").siblings().map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();

    console.log(data);
});
```

Now `data` will hold an Array of the siblings of the cell with the `edit` button.

---

If you don't need an Array, but want to work with the text directly in the loop, I'd do this instead.

```
$("tableID").on("click", ".edit_button", function() {
    $(this).closest("td").siblings().text(function(i, txt) {
        console.log(txt); // do something with the text
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried...check my update. no alerts, I thin the click is not detected.

Comment: @user2529058: Your `alert()` calls are outside the event handler. Put them inside. http://jsfiddle.net/HHs2y/

Comment: this is what the log console says : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: @user2529058: My answer doesn't use a property named "value". Nor does the new code you posted in your answer.